# Coinbase api get request does not return all records

Tags: php, coinbase-api

Here I try to  get all accounts using the coinbase api:

```
require 'MyInclude/vendor/autoload.php';
use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration; 
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account;
use Coinbase\Wallet\ActiveRecord\AccountActiveRecord;

$apiKey =  'API KEY';
$apiSecret =  'API SECERET';
$configuration = Configuration::apiKey($apiKey, $apiSecret);

$client = Client::create($configuration);

$accounts = $client->getAccounts();
```

OUTPUT : Only 25 accounts in this array

How do I get all accounts???

Answer (score 4):

Check the API Documentation.

> All GET endpoints which return an object list support cursor based
>   pagination with pagination information inside a pagination object.
>   This means that to get all objects, you need to paginate through the
>   results by always using the id of the last resource in the list as a
>   starting_after parameter for the next call.

https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#pagination

So your request just returns the 25 first results. In order to get all accounts, you need to make a loop using the returned `next_uri` (see the example response).

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "ending_before": null,
    "starting_after": null,
    "limit": 25,
    "order": "desc",
    "previous_uri": null,
    "next_uri": "/v2/accounts?&limit=25&starting_after=5d5aed5f-b7c0-5585-a3dd-a7ed9ef0e414"
  },
  "data": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the initial limit to 100 (default is 25). For example

```
client.getAccounts({limit: 100}, function(err, accounts) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error
      } else {
        // Call again if there is pagination
        if (!pagination.next_starting_after) {
            // Remember to set pagination to 100 again
            pagination.limit = 100;
            client.getAccounts({limit: 100}, function(err, accounts) {
                  // do your business logic
            });
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

in nodeJS according to [documentation](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node):

```
account.getTransactions(null, function(err, txns, pagination) {
  txns.forEach(function(txn) {
    console.log('my txn: ' + txn.id);
  });
  console.log(pagination.next_uri);
  account.getTransactions(pagination, function(err, txns) {
    txns.forEach(function(txn) {
      console.log('my txn: ' + txn.id);
    });
  });
});
```